# Pusher private chat works on localhost, not working on live server

Tags: pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-events

I have developed a chat system using laravel and Vue. Am using pusher for realtime communication. Everything works well on localhost. But on pushing to live server (shared hosting), the chat does not work. The error on pusher debug is: **Cannot broadcast client event (connection not subscribed to channel private-chat1).**
However, the message can be seen on the debug console.

Question:

- Does shared hosting has anything to do with the chatapp failing?
  Does SSL affect? (the domain is ssl installed)
  What else can I check. 
  Really tried to troubleshoot unsuccessfully.